# Add/Remove object to array based on boolean value - angular 2+/Ionic 2+

Tags: angular, object, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a list of items. That I pull down originally. Which is an array of objects. I then make a request checking if anything has changed to this array from this new endpoint. If an object has been added to this array then I need to somehow display this array with the object that was added. So inserting the new object into the old array. How would I go about this? Thanks!

Comment: What is the endpoint returning? And how are you implementing the backend call? Through observables?

Answer (score 0):

This approach is either for Angular alone or with Ionic Framework. 
You can use RxJs Library which is known for its Observables, Subject, BehaviorSubject... etc

You need to subscribe to the Object/Data you want to watch for changes.

I chose the Subject for this example and therefore not adding an initial value. You can go another way and do this

```
watcher = new BehaviorSubject(objArr);
```

It will start with the value of objArr = [{},{}] set to it.

Below is a simple example on how you can go about this.

```js
import {AfterContentInit, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  template: `
    <h1> Keep watch on new additions to Array </h1>
    <button (click)="addObj({name: 'Doe', age: 30})">Add Object</button>
    <div *ngFor="let item of objArr">
      <ul>
        <li> Name: {{item.name}}, Age: {{item.age}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterContentInit {

  //// lets say it is where the data is coming from and into.
  objArr = [
    {
      name: 'John',
      age: 20
    },
    {
      name: 'Jane',
      age: 21
    }
  ];

  watcher = new Subject();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.watcher.subscribe((data: User) => {
      console.log('Array has being modified --> ' , data);
      alert('Array has received new Data')
      this.objArr.push({name: data.name, age: data.age})
    })
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.watcher.next({name: 'Andy', age: 32})
    }, 3500)


    setTimeout(() => {
      this.watcher.next({name: 'Bob', age: 48})
    }, 6000)
  }

  addObj(data: User) {
    this.watcher.next(data)
  }
}

export interface User {
  name: string,
  age: number
}
```

You can go here for further reading and documentation http://reactivex.io/rxjs/ 
But the bottom line is that you need an Observable/etc to watch for a file change on the stream and subscribe to it receive a notification/etc. This is also a better approach to communicate between components instead using EventEmitter.
Angular is loaded with Observable where you can Subscribe to, such as the HttpClient.

Best of luck.